# Arrange the titles of the films in different columns

Tags: mysql

This query extracts

- 'id', actor's id
- 'name', name of the actor
- 'image', image of the actor
- 'film', number of films in which there is the actor
- 'title', title of the film

from the database.
[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aNZevWLBCLvFANXHH55FSh/0)

Is it possible to make sure that the films are not all
grouped in a single column, but grouped in two or more columns
distinctly?

For example,

actors id: 3, 1, 43 have two films in common
but only one is displayed.

It should be

```
  film 1 film 2
Exorcist-I, Exorcist-II
```

while the actor id: 7

```
  film 1 film 2
Exorcist-I null
```

and actor id: 42

```
  film 1 film 2
   null Exorcist-II
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What are your desired results here? It's not at all clear what "make sure that the films are not all grouped in a single column but in two or more columns distinct." means. Desired results from a query would really help.

Comment: Please post your code here, not off-site. We shouldn't have to leave this site in order to figure out what you're asking. See the [help], particularly [ask] and [mcve]. Including it here means that it remains available for future users of this site.

Comment: #JNevill, the query is clear, if you run it you realize that it reflects my question
Mr Ken White I have been criticized and insulted for not using the media type (db-fiddle)
for the umpteenth time instead of helping you criticize and you are of an unpleasant rudeness
for those who have put the least against me I only wish you well

Comment: Your fiddle example doesn't work at all and it is to big  to examine the faults. _Next i believe we solved that particular homework at least once before. But you should check out joins that will help you immensly

Comment: @nbk, I apologize for the fiddle. I tried but I never found a solution, even a similar one, that could help me.
Basically I have to work with actor table (actor_id, name, act_image), film table (film_id, title),
film_actor table (film_id, actor_id). Now I can select the actor id: 1 that returns me (rightly)
all the actors who worked with him, and the movies as id not as a title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, and excluding your restrictions

```
SELECT  
  fa1.actor_id actor_id,
  a.name  name,
  a.act_img  actimg,
  Count(*) film,
  GROUP_cONCAT(DISTINCT f1.title ORDER BY f1.film_id) title
FROM
  (SELECT 
    film_id,actor_id 
  FROM film_actor
  WHERE film_id in (select film_id 
    from film_actor where actor_id = 1)
  ) fa1 
  inner join film f1 ON fa1.film_id = f1.Film_id
  inner join actor a ON fa1.actor_id = a.actor_id
GROUP BY actor_id,name,act_img
ORDEr by film DESC
```

Gives you following result

```
actor_id    name                        actimg             film     title                          
1           Linda Blair                 l_blair.jpg        2        Exorcist,Exorcist II: the Heretic
3           Max von Sydow               m_vsydow.jpg       2        Exorcist,Exorcist II: the Heretic
43          Kitty Winn                  k_winn.jpg         2        Exorcist,Exorcist II: the Heretic
5           William O'Malley            w_omalley.jpg      1        Exorcist                       
44          Paul Henreid                p_henreid.jpg      1        Exorcist II: the Heretic       
52          Robert Symonds              r_symonds.jpg      1        Exorcist                       
6           Lee J.Cob                   l_jcob.jpg         1        Exorcist                       
45          Dana Plato                  d_plato.jpg        1        Exorcist II: the Heretic       
53          Barton Heyman               b_heyman.jpg       1        Exorcist                       
7           Eileen Dietz                e_dietz.jpg        1        Exorcist                       
46          Ned Beatty                  n_beatty.jpg       1        Exorcist II: the Heretic       
54          Robert Schündler            r_schündler.jpg    1        Exorcist                       
8           Mercedes McCambridge        m_mcambridge.jpg   1        Exorcist                       
47          James Earl Jones            j_ejones.jpg       1        Exorcist II: the Heretic       
55          Arthur Storch               a_storch.jpg       1        Exorcist                       
9           Ron Faber                   r_faber.jpg        1        Exorcist                       
48          Belinda Beatty              b_beatty.jpg       1        Exorcist II: the Heretic       
56          Barbara Cason               b_cason.jpg        1        Exorcist II: the Heretic       
2           Ellen Burstyn               e_burstyn.jpg      1        Exorcist                       
41          Richard Burton              r_burton.jpg       1        Exorcist II: the Heretic       
49          Jack MacGowran              j_macgowran.jpg    1        Exorcist                       
57          Ken Renard                  k_renard.jpg       1        Exorcist II: the Heretic       
42          Louise Fletcher             l_fletcher.jpg     1        Exorcist II: the Heretic       
50          Thomas Bermingham           t_bermingham.jpg   1        Exorcist                       
58          Karen Knapp                 no_foto.png        1        Exorcist II: the Heretic       
4           Jason Miller                j_miller.jpg       1        Exorcist                       
51          Peter Masterson             p_masterson.jpg    1        Exorcist
```

Which you can see working https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eec13d233c5b46a4eec03988cb09be2f

Your constraints don't work, because of different reasons, that's why i excluded them from the example. There are also missing tables.

I also has to eliminate '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and replace it with NULL for this example to work, because of the restrictions of the server.
.